# Launching external process from Java : stdout and stderr

Tags: java, process

I'm launching an external process from java, using the standard `java.lang.Process`.
I'm trying to figure out what the output of the process was, BUT in a format that combines both `stdout` and `stderr`.

Currently, I have `Process#getInputStream` which provides access to `stdout`, and `Process#getErrorStream` which provides access to `stderr`.
This is all good, except that we can't order the output from stdout and stderr, by their timestamp.

Say the process has an output like this:

- One line (A) written to stdout
- One line (B) written to stderr
- One line (C) written to stdout

Java won't allow us to know that the line (B) was written after (A) and before (C).
I'd like to know if there is any way to merge external process 's stdout and stderr, so that we know in which order statements were printed to output.

Comment: Just a quick q , Are these outputs of the processes that cannot be captured in Java ? Because otherwise these are log levels that you would mark in sequence into log files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) API instead of plain Runtime.exec(), then you can redirect Output and Error streams, including redirecting them to the same stream.

```
ProcessBuilder pb =
  new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2");
pb.redirectErrorStream(true); // merges err with out
pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.appendTo(new File("out.txt")));
Process p = pb.start();
p.waitFor();
```