# Read an external process's interleaved stdout and stderr exactly as they are written

Tags: java, process

I'm using `ProcessBuilder` to start a bash process.
The command that I'm executing writes to stdout and stderr.
So far I've not found a way to get stdout and stderr in the order that they where printed by the command and how they show up if I execute the command outside of Java.

Say the process has an output like this:

- One line (A) written to stdout
- One line (B) written to stderr
- One line (C) written to stdout

I want to know the exact order of the lines. So eg. that B was written before C but after A.

The answer provided in https://stackoverflow.com/a/38764695/4266296 seems to work for some people but is maybe not guaranteed on all platforms?
I'm using OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.8+10, mixed mode) on Ubuntu 20.04.

What I've tried so far:

- `processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true)`: `process.getInputStream()` starts with all the stderr lines and then stdout follows, same if I redirect the stdout to a `File`
- `processBuilder.inheritIO()`: prints directly to the console of the parent but is still not in sequential order of how the messages where written (starts with stdout followd by stderr)
- adding `2>&1` to the command: same behavior as with `redirectErrorStream(true)`

Comment: I don't have time to post a full answer, so a jumping off point: your enemy is buffering. stdout behaves differently when it goes to a terminal vs. when it's piped to another program. In the latter case it becomes [*full buffered*](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/unix-buffering). stderr, on the other hand, stays line buffered even when piped. Look into how to get stdout to be either *line buffered* or *unbuffered*.

Comment: Also, this buffering happens in the external program, not in your Java reader program. You have to modify/manipulate the other program to [disable its stdout buffering](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments by John Kugelman pointed my in the right direction. Thank you a lot!

The buffering doesn't happen on the Java side but is the result of piping stdout and stderr to another program. In this case the JVM.

> it becomes [full buffered](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/unix-buffering). stderr, on the other hand, stays line buffered even when piped.

So we want to change the buffer behavior of the external process call.

I took the `script` route described in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/61833/274368.
My code now looks something like this:

```
String command = "script -q -c \"my-command\" /dev/null";
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = fs.runInShell(command, args.toArray(new String[args.size()]));
processBuilder.directory(workingDirectory);
processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = processBuilder.start();
try (BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()))) {
    String message = input.lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
    // ...
}
```

Where `message` contains all lines from stderr and stdout in the correct order.